# Conectar a MySQL desde red externa

Tags: mysql, xampp

tengo una pregunta, estoy haciendo una aplicación para móvil con android studio, que accede a mi BBDD MySQL a través de XAMPP, pero claro esto necesito que se pueda acceder desde cualquier dispositivo, como puedo hacer esto.. gracias de antemano!

Comment: Con una API en un servidor que permita hacer `GET`, `POST`, `PUSH`, `DELETE`

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cualquier dispositivo o a cualquier ubicación? Si es ubicación, subiendo tu BBDD MySQL a un hosting en internet. El XAMPP lo habrás instalado para hacer el desarrollo en local

Comment: Como bien dice @DavidJP la BD tendría que estar alojada en un servidor remoto (generalmente un hosting ligado a un dominio) y como dice Bicho, para acceder a los datos, lo habitual es programar una API o un Servicio Web a través del cual consultas la BD desde cualquier dispositivo mandando peticiones al servidor a través de una URL (Android tiene una librería llamada `Volley` que es la que se suele usar actualmente para las peticiones). Otra opción interesante es Firebase, pero eso ya es otro mundo, lo dejo caer aquí como posibilidad por si te interesa investigar sobre ello.

Comment: gracias gente, hice el servicio web, me referia desde cualquier ubicación, cualquier movil pueda acceder a esta, pues solo me faltará colgarla a un hosting como pensaba, muchas gracias! (Y si utilicé `Volley` y perfectamente!)